# What is the regex for all digits and with special characters only + or -

Tags: python, regex

It should allow:
4-
3+
-2
1

It should not allow:
4--
3+-
%3
3%

Doing the following:`^([-+]?(?:\d+))$` but it doesn't check correctly.

Comment: your regex will only allow a `-` or a `+` only at the front of the word, you will need a group to capture those characters as many times as you would like

Comment: do you want to find matches within a sequence of digits or to match one by one separately?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a regex that works: `^[+-]?\d[+-]?$`. This will match one or more digit plus or minus on either side.

If you want to match numbers with a decimal point this one will work: `"^[\+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?[\+-]?$`

Edit* You do not need to use the escape character inside the character class. To preserve the information from my previous answer, the escape character of the `+` is `\+` and the link to the python regex documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you wan't to match the numbers separately you can use this regex:
`^\d[\+|\-]$|^[\+|\-]\d$`

Here You can see it in action [link](https://regex101.com/r/2npw8e/4)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match not all the single numbers and their signs but the whole row containing them, this regex will do the job:

`^([-+]?\d[-+]? ?)+`

Here you can play with it: https://regex101.com/r/2npw8e/2

If you just want to match each number this regex will do it:

`^[-+]?\d[-+]?$`

You maybe need to drop `^` and `$` in the regex to match the numbers not only from the beginning of a line to the end, depending on how your actual data looks like.